# Constructing a matrix associated with a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V = \{ f(x) \in \Bbb R[x] \; | \; \deg(f) ≤ 5 \} $ and $T : V \rightarrow \Bbb R^6$ defined by $$T(f) = (f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)).$$

Let $f(x) = ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ then $$T(f) = (f,a+b+c+d+e+f,32a+16b+8c+4d+2e+f,243a+81b+27c+9d+3e+f,1024a+256b+64c+16d+4e+f,3125a+625b+125c+25d+5e+f).$$

How can I construct a matrix $A$ associated with the transformation $T$? Some help please.

Comment: Does the problem ask you to construct a matrix $A$ associated with $T$?

Comment: yesss i can't  find the kernel but i can construct the matrix

Comment: If you can find the kernel and you can construct the matrix, then what's the problem? Also, the first component of $T(f)$ isn't $0$.

Comment: No i can't find the matrix associated sorry i edited

Comment: It suffices to know what it does to the basis elements 1, $x$, ..., $x^5$.

Comment: yes but im confused with the construction taking the canonical basis 1,x,...,$x^5$

Comment: What are $a,b,c,d,e$ for each element $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5$? This is the first question you must answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

To construct a matrix (for a linear transformation from finite-dimensional v.s. to another f.d. v.s.), you only need to know what it does on a basis of the domain.

In our case *a* basis is $\{1,x^2, x^3,x^4, x^5\}$. The map $T$ takes $1$ to the point $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ and the map $x$ to the point $(0,1,2,3,4,5)$ and the map $x^2$ to the point $(0,1,4,9,16,25)$. You can see how $T$ operates on the other basis elements.

Supposing we are taking the obvious basis for $\Bbb R^6$ (that is $e_1$, $e_2$, ... $e_6$), the matrix will look like
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0&0&-&-&-\\
1&1&1&-&-&-\\
1&2&4&-&-&-\\
1&3&9&-&-&-\\
1&4&16&-&-&-\\
1&5&25&-&-&-\end{pmatrix}$$